What is the difference between Allocated GPUs and GPU quota in runAI?
What is the difference between Allocated GPUs and GPU quota in runAI?



Allocated GPUs = number of GPUs currently being used in the project (i.e., sum of all GPUs of the all instances currently running + assigned to the project)
GPU quota = max number of GPUs that the project can use. Note that the it's possible to configure a project to be allowed to go over quota.

